# Powerbuilder 12.5 Executable file creation failed

Tags: executable, sybase, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

I'm trying to create an executable file for an existing project. I just made some adjustment to it but every time I tried to deploy it i'm getting below error:

> Could not create or open file C:\Users\Vanessa\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h.
>       Create of executable file failed.

I've checked the directory and there's a EN32T.err. Below is the content of error file:

> C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(1): Warning! W086: col(9)     definition of macro 'PS_UNICODE' not identical to previous definition
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(1): Note! N393: col(9) included from C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.c(4)
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(1): Note! N851: col(9) macro 'PS_UNICODE' defined on the command line
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(27): Error! E059: col(19) unable to open 'setjmp.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(325): Error! E336: col(33) declaration specifiers are required to declare 'jmp_buf'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(325): Error! E006: col(25) syntax error; probable cause: missing ';'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(326): Error! E336: col(35) declaration specifiers are required to declare 'jmp_buf'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(326): Error! E498: col(25) syntax error before 'finallyLoc'; probable cause: incorrectly spelled type name
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(327): Error! E336: col(33) declaration specifiers are required to declare 'jmp_buf'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(327): Error! E498: col(25) syntax error before 'gosubLoc'; probable cause: incorrectly spelled type name
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(328): Error! E121: col(1) syntax error
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(334): Error! E059: col(19) unable to open 'limits.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(335): Error! E059: col(18) unable to open 'float.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(336): Error! E059: col(19) unable to open 'stdarg.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(344): Error! E059: col(17) unable to open 'math.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(2901): Error! E059: col(19) unable to open 'stdlib.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(3447): Error! E059: col(18) unable to open 'tchar.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(3450): Error! E059: col(20) unable to open 'strsafe.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(3595): Error! E059: col(19) unable to open 'string.h'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4356): Error! E135: col(36) 'friend', 'virtual' or 'inline' modifiers may only be used on functions
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4356): Error! E006: col(17) syntax error; probable cause: missing ';'
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4622): Error! E135: col(34) 'friend', 'virtual' or 'inline' modifiers may only be used on functions
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4622): Error! E042: col(34) symbol 'HRESULT' already defined
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4622): Note! N392: col(34) 'int HRESULT' defined in: C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4356) (col 9)
>       C:\Users\VANESS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\EN32T.h(4622): Error! E133: col(17) too many errors: compilation aborted

Anyone can help me on how to fix this please.

Comment: What did you change? Does it still build if you revert your changes?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at http://techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Machine_Code/machine_code.html and review whether or not you really need machine code turned on. I'd strongly suspect your problem will go away, or at least manifest itself more obviously, if you deployed with a P-code option.